# QCamera Viewfinder: not shown if has a parent window

Tags: camera, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to view the camera stream using `QCameraViewfinder` in PyQt5. The problem is simple to describe: if the viewfinder has no parent, I can see it, if I set a widget as a parent, I cannot see it.

This code works (I can see a window with the stream from camera):

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
cam = QCamera()
vf = QCameraViewfinder()
cam.setViewfinder(vf)
vf.show()
cam.start()
app.exec_()
```

This doesn't work (window remains gray):

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wid = QWidget()
cam = QCamera()
vf = QCameraViewfinder(wid)
cam.start()
cam.setViewfinder(vf)
wid.show()
app.exec_()
```

I read the documentation, but I did not find anything related to this, probably I have missed something.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works after setting `cam.viewfinder` before `cam.start` and setting `setGeometry()` for widget and viewfinder e.g.:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wid = QWidget()
wid.setGeometry(20,200,700,600)
cam = QCamera()
vf = QCameraViewfinder(wid)
vf.setGeometry(50,50,600,550)
cam.setViewfinder(vf)
cam.start()
wid.show()
app.exec_()
```